# A club has $7$ members: $4$ women and $3$ men. A subcommittee consisting of $2$ people is chosen at random.

Tags: probability

1. Find the probabilities of the three events that the subcommittee has no women, one women, and two women.

I've tried to do this but I keep getting $\frac{6}{42}$ for $0$, $\frac{12}{42}$ for $1$, and $\frac{12}{42}$ for $2$. I feel like this is wrong because these probabilities don't add up to $1$.

2. What is the expected value of women on the subcommittee?

I ve tried this with my answers for part $1$ but I get a number less than $1$ which also doesn't make any logical sense.

Comment: For one of each, you probably thought woman, man. There is also man, woman, so $24/42$ for one of each.

Comment: In the long run, it is more useful to think this way. There are $\binom{7}{2}$ equally likely committees of $2$. There are $\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}$ committees with one man, one woman.

Answer (score 1):

There are $_7C_2 = 21$ possible subcommittees.  Three of these have no women ($_3C_2$ from among the men), twelve have one woman (pick the woman ($4$), then pick the man ($3$)), and six have two women ($_4C_2$).

So the probabilities are $1/7, 4/7, 2/7$ for no, one, and two females, respectively.

The expected value then is $0 \cdot 1/7 + 1 \cdot 4/7 + 2 \cdot 2/7 \approx 1.14$.